# macvim + Latex + results compilation?

Tags: vim, latex, macvim

Yes, I'm contemplating to switch from emacs to vim (a big decision in a programmer's life!), but I have problems setting up vim for latex editing.

My problem is the following:

I use macvim in combination with the excellent vim-latex suite. I learned that I can compile the .tex files  using the command `\ll`, but the problem is that the results of this process are shown on a temporary window, which is immediately removed after the process is finished (the window is kept opened only if there are some errors).

Now, I would like to know how I can tell vim to keep this window visible, at least for one or two seconds, so that I can check if the details of the compilation process (e.g. the number of pages produced). I found out that the command `:copen` re-opens the window, but it shows only a few lines, and not all the results of the compilation.

Does any of you know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Find the place in the plugin where the external *Latex* tool is invoked, and append `; sleep 2` to it to keep the window for a little while longer.

As the *quickfix list* in Vim (`:copen`) is filled, you could also edit the `'errorformat'` option; it determines which lines from the output are parsed and added to the list.

But none of that is trivial for a beginner in Vim. Why don't you try to submit an enhancement request to the plugin's author?

Answer (score 0):

I use a rather dodgy combination of mapping and script calling to compile my TEX documents that could potentially help you out :

```
"Add this to the content  of ~/.vimrc
:map ® :! ./render.sh <CR> <CR>     //® is just Alt+r on a mac
:map Â :! ./render.sh <CR>      //Same thing but with Alt+z
```

and place a `render.sh`, chmoded+x compiling script in your working directory :

```
#Content of render.sh
/usr/texbin/pdflatex YourFile.tex <<EOF
s   //Whatever compiling options you may want to use
EOF
open /Applications/Preview.app YourFile.pdf //Open the PDF File, or don't ;)
```

You can now compile using `Alt+r` or `Alt+z`, the second one displaying the compiling `stdout` and going back to vim straight away, the first one stopping, being scrollable and waiting for a carriage return. You could even imagine grepping out errors or warning in the render script, it's up to you.

EDIT : This works fine in VIM but it seems you may need absolute paths for your `render.sh` script when working with MacVim (a simple `:! ls` shows the working directory would be ~).

EDIT2 : Yes, it does. Put `render.sh` in your home and we'll find a way to localize it later if you like the idea ;)